# .Net Core 2.2 XML Serialization/Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I am unable to serialize/deserialize XML in .Net Core 2.2.

I am receiving the following exception: System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XPathMessageFilter' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

I have Googled, of course, to no avail thus far.

I have added the System.ServiceModel.Primitives NuGet package but the XPathMessageFilter type isn't contained in that package. Has anyone had success with this issue?

Comment: `XPathMessageFilter` falls under "advanced stuff that nobody has taken the time and effort to port yet because it's relatively under-used". This is probably not going to be part of .NET Core 3 either. You can do XML serialization in Core, but not necessarily the way you're doing it now. Any chance you can share the code for that (and details on what you're serializing)?

Comment: Atm is not in 3.0 preview 6. Consider other serialization options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=netcore-3.0&term=XPathMessageFilter

Comment: Wonderful. I am attempting to utilize the HttpClient's PostAsXmlAsync extension method and the ReadAsAsync<T> method to interact with a third-party API. The target types are not under my control. I could create transient types and mappers to get the job done I suppose but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I'm not clear on how, precisely, `PostAsXmlAsync` does its job, but you might get around its restrictions by doing the XML serialization yourself, without necessarily having to map every individual target type. Core supports basic XML serialization, but not necessarily whatever `PostAsXmlAsync` is doing.

Comment: I have tried using basic XML serialization as well but I receive an InvalidOperationException as there is unexpected data in the XML returned by the API I am calling.

Comment: We have an implementation in 4.6.1 that works without incident. I think it's time to reconsider whether we need to use core for this third-party API. It appears to be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: If you are not using Core because you want this to run on Linux, then yes, it almost certainly is more trouble than it's worth because you get little benefit from making Core run old crusty serialization code. The main benefits of Core are cross platform support and perf improvements (both from the jitter and rewrites to use `Span`), but if you're gunning for the latter you're probably better off overhauling the use of the framework's default XML serialization to begin with, which has never been particularly fast.

Comment: By [.NET (Core) 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/), if you can wait that long, this code should run out of the box.

Comment: I considered .Net 5 but I can't wait. There is no benefit to using Core for this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error depends on the version of Net being used.  Net 4.0 required having Net 1.0,2.0,2.2, 3.0, 3.5 installed.  The new Net like 4.6.1 contains all the older version of Net.  So I would check installed software and see what version of Net are installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [System.Xml Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml?view=netcore-2.2) for serializing/de-serializing and navigating XML documents in dotnet core.

[System.ServiceModel Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel?view=netframework-4.8) works with dotnet framework.